# Smooth free hand drawing brush in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, draw, uibezierpath

In trying to develop an drawing app, where i can able draw line, circle and letter, etc. But drawn lines are not in smooth. Is there any sdk or library for variety of brush for smooth drawing.

Here is my screenshot of drawn lines[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Increase the resolution of your ViewController so that the brush has more pixels to fill and will appear smoother.